# How to calculate this integral using the Residues Theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Evaluate the following integral using residue's theorem:
$$\oint_C\frac{\cos(z)}{e^{iz}+1}\mathrm{d}z$$

where $C:|z+3\pi|=2$.

I got stuck when I tried to calculate the residue on pole $z=-3\pi$, I couldn't go too far with this limit $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to\ -3\pi}\frac{(z+3\pi)\cos(z)}{e^{iz}+1}$

Comment: Just use l'Hopital

Comment: Oh exactly,thanks! Somehow I've committed some mistake when I first tried it. Pretty simple so. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach (the result is the same as using l'Hopital's rule)

The function $$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+1}{z+3\pi}$$ is a difference quotient, and its limit as $z\to -3\pi$ is the derivative of $e^{iz}$ at $z=-3\pi$, so

$$\lim_{z\to -3\pi} f(z) = i e^{-3\pi i} = -i$$
and
$$\lim_{z\to\ -3\pi}\frac{(z+3\pi)\cos(z)}{e^{iz}+1} = \frac{\cos(- 3\pi)}{-i}=-i.$$